# How to get different sessions with jsp under tomcat in java?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

That is my first question :)

I have a Tomcat server and I am programming an online quiz. The user types his name, goes to the next page where the opponents are displayed, picks one and starts the quiz with 5 questions. When the questions are over, he gets the results and receives a button to go to the opponents page. This works very well.

Unfortunately when I use another device/browser to simulate another user, and the first user is answering question 2 for example, this user overwrites the other.

I tried:

- creating a new session when the user picks an opponent -> same behavior.
- creating a cookie for the game when the user picks an opponent -> same behavior.

Can someone help me? That's my first time with Tomcat/Dynamic Webapp and I thought each user would get an own session if they start from another browser/device.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could be using Application context instead of Session. Difficult to sayi workout seeing your code.

Comment: what are you using for this? Servlet to JSP or Spring MVC?

Comment: I am using Servlet to JSP...
For a code example, can I edit my question? o.O it seems i cant...

Comment: Are you trying to simulate two separate users? Best way would be to login with two separate browsers (e.g. Chrome & ff) so there is no session-confusion.

Comment: I do this way ;) I have 5 questions but when a user on one browser answers one question, the user on the other browser gets the update too. Like if they would share the same game, but I start a new game with different users/opponents to be safe... I create a new object of the game with new 5 questions everytime a user picks a new opponent... so I dont get why/how they are sharing the questions.

Comment: Here my post method:

`if(request.getParameter("anmeldenbutton")!=null){
String spielerNickname=request.getParameter("spielerNicknameTextFeld");
request.getSession(true);
Spieler neuerSpieler = new Spieler(spielerNickname);
SpielerKontroller.addSpielerZumKontroller(neuerSpieler);
request.setAttribute("angemeldeterspieler",neuerSpieler);
request.setAttribute("gegnerliste",SpielerKontroller.getGegnerListe(neuerSpieler));
request.getRequestDispatcher("/angemeldeterspieler.jsp").forward(request,response);
}` Sorry I cant edit my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

I just had to create a new session after the Button check:

```
if(request.getParameter("anmeldenbutton")!=null)
    {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        String spielerNickname = request.getParameter("spielerAnmeldungTextFeld");
        boolean spielerKannErzeugtWerden = SpielerKontroller.addSpielerNicknameZuKontroller(spielerNickname);
        Spieler neuerSpieler;
        if(spielerKannErzeugtWerden)
        {   
            neuerSpieler = new Spieler(spielerNickname);
            SpielerKontroller.addSpielerZuKontroller(neuerSpieler);
            session.setAttribute("angemeldeterspieler", neuerSpieler);
            session.setAttribute("gegnerliste", SpielerKontroller.getGegnerListe(neuerSpieler));

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/angemeldeterspieler.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```